# Reed switch input to an Android

Tags: java, android, input, usb, output

I'm trying to make a dead reckoning device for Android, similar to a bicycle computer. I have a reed switch and a magnet for the input, and the plan is to count the number of pulses using an Android application. As I understand it I can:

1) Use the headphone jack. If I can provide an output voltage to the switch, when the magnet passes the input voltage should drop to zero. I know about AudioRecord, but I'm not sure if it's possible to simultaneously output to and take input from the headphone jack, which would be necessary.

2) Use the usb. I know this is probably the better way, as it allows me to use the reed switch as a digital input, but I would like to avoid buying an IOIO if possible as I only need one input. I can solder the usb pins to the switch, but is it possible to make a simple driver for that?

3) Use both. I can take power from the usb and audio input from the switch output. Is it necessary to use a driver just to draw usb power, or is it on by default?

What would you guys recommend? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Use the headphone jack. If I can provide an output voltage to the switch, when the magnet passes the input voltage should drop to zero. I know about AudioRecord, but I'm not sure if it's possible to simultaneously output to and take input from the headphone jack, which would be necessary.

looks like a good solution. no extra circuit. (do add proper protection for worst case)
also, you need two states output so, some kind of pull-to-inactive state will be required to keep in inactive state by defalt. (or you will be having false counts)

> 2) Use the usb. I know this is probably the better way, as it allows me to use the reed switch as a digital input, but I would like to avoid buying an IOIO if possible as I only need one input

also, look good but a uC and other stuff can be burden.
or you could connect a uC on bluetooh and send data via bluetooth.
(note: uC also need power)

> I can solder the usb pins to the switch, but is it possible to make a simple driver for that?

**NO!!!!**  its USB (Universal Serial Bus) which has a protocol, **USB is not GPIO.**

> 3) Use both. I can take power from the usb and audio input from the switch output. Is it necessary to use a driver just to draw usb power, or is it on by default?

since you need power to pull up, you need to a power source.

- generate from the movement?
- usb?
- Audio out? (but with poper protection. it is meant for driving small speakers not as a power source)